# How to limited Animated decay with animation value

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native

I want to set a minimum and a maximum toValue for animation

```
this.myAnimated = new Animated.ValueXY() ;
```

and in PanResponder

```
onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
      this.myAnimated.flattenOffset();

      Animated.decay(this.myAnimated, {
          deceleration: 0.997,
          velocity: {x: 0, y: gestureState.vy},
      }).start();
}
```

I hope I could get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved for me like this

```
this._value = {x: 0, y: 0};

this.myAnimated.addListener((value) => {

    if (value.y < 100 && value.y > 500 )
       Animated.decay(this.state.myAnimated).stop();

    this._value = value
});
```

Comment: In addition, it would be good to remove the listener by calling .removeListener(id) if you're done using it